# React to render another component condionally

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to the World of React. I have the following functional component for the login page.

I'd like it to render `OtpInput` component when user clicks on the `Verify Email` button and there's no error i.e. `emailError` is null.

```
import { BaseSyntheticEvent, useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from '@fluentui/react-components';
import styles from './Login.module.scss';
import LoginField from '../../core/components/LoginField';
import OtpInput from '../../core/components/multi-factor-authentication/Multi-factor-authentication';

export default function Login(): JSX.Element {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState('');
  // Multi-factor authentication.
  const [otp, setOtp] = useState('');
  const onChangeOtp = (value: string) => setOtp(value);

  const handleVerifyEmail = (): void => {
    if (email) {
      setEmailError('');
    } else if (!email) {
      setEmailError('Please enter your email.');
    }
  };

  const div = (
    <div className={styles.loginContainer}>
      <div className={styles.loginSection}>
        <div className={styles.loginControls}>
          <div className={styles.logoContainer}>
            <div className={styles.logo} />
            <h1 color="secondary">Alytic</h1>
          </div>
          <LoginField
            title="Email"
            required
            size="large"
            onChange={(e: BaseSyntheticEvent) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            validationState={emailError ? 'error' : undefined}
            validationMessage={emailError}
            label="Email"
          />
          <Button onClick={handleVerifyEmail}>Verify Email</Button>
        </div>
      </div>
      {emailError !== '' ? (
        <div>
          <h1>Enter your code</h1>
          <h3>Enter the 6-digit security code from your authenticator app.</h3>
          <OtpInput value={otp} valueLength={6} onChange={onChangeOtp} />
          <Button appearance="primary" shape="rounded" size="medium">
            Continue
          </Button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p>Test</p>
        </div>
      )}
      <div className={styles.loginImage} />
    </div>
  );

  return div;
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. What part didn't execute well?

Comment: @ShriHariL it doesn't render the `OtpInput` component when I provide an email address and click on the Verify Email button. No errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because if the email is good, `emailError !== ''` will be false. Have a separate state for labelling whether the email is verified. Keep `emailError` for validation message only.

```jsx
import { BaseSyntheticEvent, useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "@fluentui/react-components";
import styles from "./Login.module.scss";
import LoginField from "../../core/components/LoginField";
import OtpInput from "../../core/components/multi-factor-authentication/Multi-factor-authentication";

export default function Login(): JSX.Element {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState("");
  // Multi-factor authentication.
  const [otp, setOtp] = useState("");
  const onChangeOtp = (value: string) => setOtp(value);
  const [isVerified, setIsVerified] = useState(false);

  const handleVerifyEmail = (): void => {
    if (email) {
      setIsVerified(true);
      setEmailError("");
    } else {
      setEmailError("Please enter your email.");
      setIsVerified(false);
    }
  };

  const div = (
    <div className={styles.loginContainer}>
      <div className={styles.loginSection}>
        <div className={styles.loginControls}>
          <div className={styles.logoContainer}>
            <div className={styles.logo} />
            <h1 color="secondary">Alytic</h1>
          </div>
          <LoginField
            title="Email"
            required
            size="large"
            onChange={(e: BaseSyntheticEvent) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            validationState={emailError ? "error" : undefined}
            validationMessage={emailError}
            label="Email"
          />
          <Button onClick={handleVerifyEmail}>Verify Email</Button>
        </div>
      </div>
      {isVerified ? (
        <div>
          <h1>Enter your code</h1>
          <h3>Enter the 6-digit security code from your authenticator app.</h3>
          <OtpInput value={otp} valueLength={6} onChange={onChangeOtp} />
          <Button appearance="primary" shape="rounded" size="medium">
            Continue
          </Button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p>Some Text Here</p>
        </div>
      )}
      <div className={styles.loginImage} />
    </div>
  );

  return div;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid issue persists and `OtpInput` block is not getting rendered.

Comment: Include `<LoginField>` code in the question

Comment: Many thanks for your help on this issue. Issue was due to the styling where `loginContainer` suppressed the containment area for `OtpInput` component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator) for conditionally rendering a component.

Define logic for the condition inside a function, then define a boolean variable to hold the status of the condition and use that variable to the check the evaluate the condition before rendering the component.

checkout the below article to gain more insight on conditional rendering in react
[Conditional Rendering in React](https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering)